# Java JNI- What's the benefit of GetString() vs. GetStringCritical()?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

According to JNI docs, `GetStringCritical()` disable garbage collection while you hold on to some memory managed by the JVM. Using this instead of `GetString()` puts your native at risks of deadlock if you call into the Java layer or perform blocking operation before `ReleaseStringCritical()` is invoked. So what's the benefit of the Critical function, and if it's synonomous, disabling garbage collection while you access JVM managed memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a correction: according to the specs, the `GetXxxCritical()` methods **may** disable garbage collection.

> So what's the benefit of the Critical function,

The advantage of using the `GetXxxCritical()` methods is that they are more likely to return a pointer to the original data rather than a copy of the data.  This means that they are likely to be faster.  Of course, this comes at a cost in terms of the documented restrictions / caveats.

> ... and is it synonymous with disabling garbage collection while you access JVM managed memory?

Well no; see my correction.  The methods **may** disable garbage collection, or they **may not**.  It will depend on how your platform implements the JNI interfaces, and possibly on other things such as JVM garbage collector options.